# How to create a web service method to be accessed from Javascript in ASP .Net (Aspx)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services, client

I need to download a list of pdf files, but I need to send the list of name files to a method as parameters in code behind to handle these. I tried with Page Methods, and Web Methods, but since these are static I can't use Response.

Then I read that the way I have to do it or one way is using a web service, since the methods can be non static. 
But it gets little messy or tricky since I only need to call a method in code behind being non static.

I have never used Web Services and I don't Know the level of complexity in the code that I need since I only need the mentioned method.

I just tried Page and Web method and it was kind of simple. Could you guide me in this situation, I have not found a clear example. I want to call the method from javascript.

Thanks a lot,
Regards.

Comment: Have you tried PHP?

Comment: I have the project advanced in asp net, Thanks for the suggestion Russ :)

Comment: Hello, I got it following the instructions of this page: 

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-Web-Service-ASMX-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx

Thanks,
Best Regards

Comment: Please post your answer below and accept it.

Comment: I can't.. We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using full .net framework, or .net core? I hope this doesn't add to your confusion, but if you have the option to use .net core I'd recommend it. Creating WebAPI's is quite easy. Check out [Microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I'm using Web Forms (Aspx)

Comment: Hello, I got it following the instructions of this page: 

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-Web-Service-ASMX-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx

Thanks,
Best Regards

Comment: Glad you got it working. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!